# Multinomial Summary output to dataframe in R

Tags: r

I created a multinomial logistic regression below:

I've stored the coefficients, standard errors, z statistic, and p values in different variables.
I'm trying to create a dataframe to store all of this information.

```
library(foreign)
library(nnet)
ml <- read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")
ml$prog2 <- relevel(ml$prog, ref = "academic")
test <- multinom(prog2 ~ 1, data = ml)

coeff <- summary(test)$coefficients
std.errs <- summary(test)$standard.errors

# calculate z-statistics of coefficients
z_stats <- summary(test)$coefficients/
  summary(test)$standard.errors

# convert to p-values
p_values <- (1 - pnorm(abs(z_stats)))*2

> std.errs
         (Intercept)
general    0.1781742
vocation   0.1718249
> coeff
         (Intercept)
general   -0.8472980
vocation  -0.7419374
> p_values
          (Intercept)
general  1.980067e-06
vocation 1.574605e-05
> z_stats
         (Intercept)
general    -4.755448
vocation   -4.317984
```

This is my expected output. How can i create this dataframe from the variables I've created? I'm having trouble using the (Intercept) column to create general_intercept. I want this to be done through dplyr.

```
feature             coefficient std.error  pval z.stat
general_intercept   -0.8472980  0.1781742  1.980067e-06  -4.755448       
vocation_intercept  -0.7419374  0.1718249  1.574605e-05 -4.317984
```

I need it to be dynamic also to the number of variables.
For example if I ran this multinomial logistic regression

```
multinom(prog ~ ses + write, data=mdata)
```

I would get this table structure:

```
feature             coefficient  std.error p.val z_stat
academic_intercept         
academic_sesmiddle              
academic_seshigh
vocation_intercept 
vocation_sesmiddle
vocation_seshigh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- cbind(coeff, std.errs, p_values, z_stats)
colnames(df) <- c("coefficient", "SE", "p_val", "z_stat")

         coefficient        SE        p_val    z_stat
general   -0.8472980 0.1781742 1.980067e-06 -4.755448
vocation  -0.7419374 0.1718249 1.574605e-05 -4.317984
```

If you want to rename the row index:

```
rownames(df) <- c("general_intercept", "vocation_intercept")

                   coefficient        SE        p_val    z_stat
general_intercept   -0.8472980 0.1781742 1.980067e-06 -4.755448
vocation_intercept  -0.7419374 0.1718249 1.574605e-05 -4.317984
```

To dynamically change the row names you can:

```
rownames(df) <- paste(rownames(df), tolower(gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", colnames(coeff))), sep = "_")

                   coefficient        SE        p_val    z_stat
general_intercept   -0.8472980 0.1781742 1.980067e-06 -4.755448
vocation_intercept  -0.7419374 0.1718249 1.574605e-05 -4.317984
```

EDIT: With the new requirements, we can write a function that can do this. This is a bit monolithic and could probably be split into several functions. Note, that in order for this to work the objects must be passed in as a named list. This function is written to work with how you have already defined the various statistics ex. `coeff <- summary(test)$coefficients`. In addition to the packages you use, it required `reshape2` and `dplyr`.

```
create_summary = function(stats) {
  if (!is.list(stats)) {
    stop("Argument must be a named list")
  }
  df = NULL
  for (i in 1:length(stats)) {
    stat = as.data.frame(stats[[i]])
    stat$feature = rownames(stat)
    stat = stat %>%
      melt(id.vars = c("feature")) %>%
      mutate(feature = paste(feature,
                             tolower(gsub(pattern = "[^a-zA-Z]",
                                          replacement = "",
                                          variable)),
                             sep = "_")) %>%
      select(feature, value)

    colnames(stat) = c("feature", names(stats)[i])
    if (is.null(df)) {
      df = stat
    } else {
      df = merge(df, stat, by = "feature")
    }
  }
  return(df)
}
```

With the initial model `test <- multinom(prog2 ~ 1, data=ml)`:

```
create_summary((list(coefficients = coeff,
                     se = std.errs,
                     p_val = p_values,
                     z_stat = z_stats)))

             feature coefficients        se        p_val    z_stat
1  general_intercept   -0.8472980 0.1781742 1.980067e-06 -4.755448
2 vocation_intercept   -0.7419374 0.1718249 1.574605e-05 -4.317984
```

With your second model `test <- multinom(prog ~ ses + write, data=ml)`:

```
             feature coefficients         se      p_val     z_stat
1 academic_intercept  -2.85197258 1.16643741 0.01448407 -2.4450284
2   academic_seshigh   1.16282574 0.51422150 0.02373868  2.2613324
3 academic_sesmiddle   0.53329140 0.44373191 0.22942845  1.2018324
4     academic_write   0.05792480 0.02141092 0.00682251  2.7053858
5 vocation_intercept   2.36609732 1.17425127 0.04390634  2.0149838
6   vocation_seshigh   0.18021764 0.64845085 0.78107356  0.2779203
7 vocation_sesmiddle   0.82463840 0.49012366 0.09246981  1.6825109
8     vocation_write  -0.05567514 0.02333135 0.01701977 -2.3862803
```

You can continue to add features and the summary will grow in length.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Do you have one where dplyr is used and also a dynamic one where the user doesn't have to specify the rownames manually?

Comment: When you say dynamically, do you just want `_intercept` appended to the end of whatever the row name is? If not, where do the row names come from?

Comment: It's whatever the column name is. In this case (Intercept) is the only column since I am fitting an intercept only model. If I fit given other features there would be more feature columns.

Comment: Hey I just updated my question. This works but it's not dynamic to the number of features fit. For example, if i added another variable to the model. the colnames(df) breaks.

Comment: @Eisen Ah, I think I see what you are looking for now. See edit.